# Add/Remove Fields on Form

Tags: jquery, html

Hey I'm trying to make a form page with addable and removable fields.  The "Add Field" button works fine, but the "Remove Field" won't work.  Anybody know why?

HTML

```
<div id="email">
<div>Primary Email:
<input type="text" name="email" length="40" />
</div>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" id="addField">Add New Field</a>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var i = 1;
$("#addField").click(function () {
var targetDiv = $(this).prev('div');
$('<div>Pretend this is a text box <a href="#" id="rem" >Remove Field</a></div>').appendTo(targetDiv);
i++;
});

$('#rem').click(function () {
$(this).closest('div').remove();
});

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's bad practice (and might fail) if you're adding multiple elements with the same ID, which it looks like you have the potential to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Id should be unique, so instead of using `rem` as id use it as a class

So change

```
$('<div>Pretend this is a text box <a href="#" id="rem" >Remove Field</a></div>').appendTo(targetDiv);
```

to

```
$('<div>Pretend this is a text box <a href="#" class="rem" >Remove Field</a></div>').appendTo(targetDiv);
```

Then since you are working with dynamically added controls use event delegation model with .on()

```
$(document).on('click','.rem', function () {
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/J4tYC/1/)

Comment: @CodyGuldner yes have you heard about event delegation and dynamic elements

Comment: @CodyGuldner if you look at the solution carefully I had done a mistake `$(body)` instead of `$(document)`, I've created a demo